# Planar graphs - more or less

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

A graph is [planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) if it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges do not cross each other.

A graph is [$k$-planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph) if it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that each of its edges is crossed at most $k$ times.

There is also a concept of [almost planar graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPlanarGraph.html) that relies on edge deletions or contractions.

I am dealing with another kind of graphs: they can be drawn in the plane in such a way that at most $k$ pairs of edges intersect.

Is there a terminology for such graphs?

Comment: Should the title be "Not quite planar graphs"?

Comment: These are the graphs with pairwise crossing number at most $k$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#:~:text=In%20graph%20theory%2C%20the%20crossing,its%20crossing%20number%20is%20zero.

Comment: Made my comment into an answer below with some more info.

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks, I edited the title to a better (I think/hope) title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the graphs with *pairwise crossing number* or *pair-crossing number* at most $k$. Note that it is an open problem whether the pair-crossing number is actually equal to the usual [crossing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)) of a graph.  See [Crossing number, pair-crossing number, and expansion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895604000437) and [The Graph Crossing Number and its Variants: A Survey](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS21) for more info.

Comment: There is also Marcus Schaefer's dynamic survey updated most recently in April this year:
[link](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS21)

Comment: Thanks Brendan!  I added the reference.